# Proof that $\forall k\in\mathbb Z^+$, $\lfloor\log_2(2k+1)\rfloor=\lfloor\log_2(2k)\rfloor$

Tags: proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I wrote a proof for this but am not completely sure if this is valid. Specifically, can I go from $m\leq k+0.5$ to $m\leq k$ because $m,k\in\mathbb Z^+$ with no further explanation? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

**Proof.** Let $n=\lfloor\log_2(2k+1)\rfloor$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}
n&\leq\log_2(2k+1)\lt n+1&&\text{(since $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, $\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x\lt x+1$),}\\
\implies2^n&\leq2k+1\lt2^{n+1}&&\text{(by algebra).}\\
\end{align*}$$
Observe that $2^n\in2\mathbb Z^+$ so $2^n=2m$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z^+$. Thus,
$$\begin{align*}
2m&\leq2k+1&&\text{(since $2m=2^n\leq2k+1$),}\\
\implies m&\leq k+0.5&&\text{(by algebra),}\\
\implies m&\leq k&&\text{(since $m,k\in\mathbb Z^+$),}\\
\implies 2m&\leq2k&&\text{(by algebra),}\\
\implies 2^n&\leq2k&&\text{(since $2^n=2m$),}\\
\implies 2^n&\leq2k\lt2^{n+1}&&\text{(since $2k+1\lt2^{n+1}\rightarrow2k\lt2^{n+1}$),}\\
\implies n&\leq\log_2(2k)\lt n+1&&\text{(by algebra),}\\
\therefore n&=\lfloor\log_2(2k)\rfloor&&\text{(since $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, $\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x\lt x+1$).}
\end{align*}$$
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: In your latter paragraph it seems you can just go from line $1$ to lines $4/5$

Comment: Your proof looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Note that for all $n \in \mathbb{N_{>0}} $ there exist $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^m \leq n < 2^{m+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This value $m$ is $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$
And $n$ increases passed a power of $2$ the value $m$ will increase by $1$.

If $n$ increases (by $1$) from an even value to an odd value the $m$ will not change (provided $n>1$). So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lfloor\log_2(2k+1)\rfloor = \lfloor\log_2(2k)\rfloor.
\end{eqnarray*}